# Failed to switch between different git accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I followed http://mherman.org/blog/2013/09/16/managing-multiple-github-accounts/#.WNGAW3QrLdR and pretty sure I'm using my newly generated ssh keys.

When I do `ssh -T personal`, `Hi XXX! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` pops up.

But when I git push, it still shows up github that the commit is from my work account, associated with my work email. Do you know where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the remotes - `git remote -v` See what the origin is pointing to personal or work.

Comment: Note that your ssh keys have nothing to do with the names/emails that show up in your got commits.  Those are controlled by the git configuration settings `user.name` and `user.email`.  Those can be set globallly and/or per-repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks larsks!

Check `git config --get user.email` and it should point to my personal email, so I fixed it by `git config --local user.email my@personal.email`